# why Html.checkboxfor is not sends or changes the boolean value of the model?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, model-view-controller

I have a simple project that allows the customer to select multiple users and remove them from the `DataBase`. But the check boxes are not change or sent the `isSelected` variable which is tells the server that which users are have to be removed.

Client Side:

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.User>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@{ 
    int i;
}
<h2><strong>جدول</strong></h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("اضافه کردن کاربر", "Create"
        , null, new { @class = "btn btn-success", @id = "btnCreate" })
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger hidden" id="btnMultipleDelete" value="حذف کاربران" />
    </p>
    <table class="table" border="0" style="user-select: none;">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <strong>نام</strong>
            </th>
            <th>
                <strong>نام خانوادگی</strong>
            </th>
            <th>
                <strong>سنّ</strong>
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        @for(i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
        {
            <tr class="mainList" id="tr-@i"
                onmouseover="changeCurrentRow(this.id), mouseIn(true)"
                onmouseout="clearCurrentRow(), mouseIn(false)">
                <td class="IndexInfo">
                    <span class="IndexText">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.ToList()[i].User_FirstName)
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td class="IndexInfo">
                    <span class="IndexText">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.ToList()[i].User_LastName)
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td class="IndexInfo">
                    <span class="IndexText persianNumber">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.ToList()[i].User_Age)
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td align="center" style="flex:3">
                    @Html.ActionLink("ویرایش", "Edit", new { id = Model.ToList()[i].User_Id },
                        new { @class = "btn btn-primary", @id = "btnEdit-" + i })
                    @Html.ActionLink("مشاهده", "Details", new { id = Model.ToList()[i].User_Id },
                        new { @class = "btn btn-secondary", @id = "btnDetail-" + i })
                    @Html.ActionLink("حذف", "Delete", new { id = Model.ToList()[i].User_Id },
                        new { @class = "btn btn-warning", @id = "btnDelete-" + i })
                    @Html.HiddenFor(u => u.ToList()[i].User_Id)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(u => u.ToList()[i].User_FirstName)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(u => u.ToList()[i].User_LastName)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(u => u.ToList()[i].User_Age)
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(u => u.ToList()[i].IsSelected, new { @class = "", @id = "cb-" + i })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>
}
```

Server Side:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(IEnumerable<User> users)
        {
            if (users.Count() == 0)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                User user;
                foreach (User u in users)
                {
                    if (u.IsSelected)
                    {
                        user = db.Users.ToList().Find(x => x.User_Id == u.User_Id);
                        db.Users.Remove(user);
                    }
                }
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
```

notice that i have tried to put a hidden input for `isSelected` Variable But that still doesn't work

Comment: HI, did you test that your view is successful calling the API controller? From what I see, your form won't be able to call the API controller.

Comment: yes, the the view does can call the controller; but the `IsSelected` user variables of input  controller are always false even when you had ticked the checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

so, while no one cares about my question i found the solution by my self.
`Controller` can not receive the `IsSelected` property from the `View` because i have changed the identity of the checkbox like id,name and ...
that means if i dont change the the identities of the checkbox, the code will works but even this solution leads us to another problem that you no longer can find the checkbox by `JS`. so i dont give this answer green tick until someone finds a better way to fix it.

for this solution something that you have to do is change the check box code from this:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(u => u.ToList()[i].IsSelected, new { @class = "", @id = "cb-" + i })
```

to this:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(u => u.ToList()[i].IsSelected})
```

and it basically will works.